# Ho to write the condition of a set in several lines?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, decorations

I would like to initiate a set, divided into the left section for the contained elements, and the right section for description of the necessarily fulfilled condition, where the right part might contain more than one line.

In a concrete case, initiating the set

```
\{\langle x,y\rangle\vert x\in p^1_{ij}(\mathscr{H}),\Vert x\Vert =1, y\in p^1_{kl}(\mathscr{H}),\Vert y\Vert=1\}
```

[image: Example of a set I want to rearrange in the described manner]

I would like to put

```
y\in p^1_{kl}(\mathscr{H}),\Vert y\Vert=1\
```

into a new line.
Could you give me a solution?

Comment: Is this in an equation environment or just inline text?

Comment: I used the align environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `aligned` (or `array`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

This is over two lines
\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \langle x,y\rangle \;\middle|\;
  \begin{aligned}
  & x\in p^1_{ij}(\mathscr{H}),\lVert x\rVert =1,\\
  & y\in p^1_{kl}(\mathscr{H}),\lVert y\rVert=1
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}
and this is on the same line, which I find clearer
\begin{equation}
\{
  \langle x,y\rangle \mid
  x\in p^1_{ij}(\mathscr{H}),\lVert x\rVert =1,
  y\in p^1_{kl}(\mathscr{H}),\lVert y\rVert=1
\}
\end{equation}
or, as well,
\begin{equation}
\{
  \langle x,y\rangle \mid
  x\in p^1_{ij}(\mathscr{H}),
  y\in p^1_{kl}(\mathscr{H}),
  \lVert x\rVert =1,
  \lVert y\rVert=1
\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\vert` is not good for the bar in set notation, use `\mid` instead. Also `\Vert` should be distinguished into `\lVert` and `\rVert` (similarly for the absolute value it's better `\lvert...\rvert` than `|...|`).

Comment: Thanks, that helps me out with my stated problem. Now I want to equate to such sets, but put the second set into a second line. As the `\\ `  -command does not work in the equation environment, and I want to use some command like `& ` for adjustion, I don't know how to get along. Could you help me out again?

Comment: @user153906 You should use `align` or similar environment.